Opening probability of a voltage-dependent ion channel
Does the opening probability of a voltage-dependent ion channel depend on the unitary conductance?
I think so because of the equation: 
but I am not sure.

Can you explain your thinking? Maybe mention what the variables in that equation represent and how it leads you to the question posed.

Now I realize that the equation is true for Squid giant axon. And the reason i think that the opening probability of a voltage dependent ion channel depend on the unitary conductance is because of the substates which depended in specific unitary conductance of this spesific state. AM i wrong?

I'm not following your comment, sorry. I think it would help to talk in terms of the variables in the equation if it's the equation that is motivating you.
